# checking array with string

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to check whether the user visited page is there in the access list of user table.

like this i am getting page name from URL

```
$q1 =  basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$var1 = "/".$q1;
```

And from database i am getting the pagename for logged in user and checking the pagename using `in_array` function like this

```
$m1 = "select pages.page_id, pages.code, pages.page, pages.href, access_level.page_id, access_level.user_id FROM pages INNER JOIN access_level ON pages.page_id=access_level.page_id WHERE access_level.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
//echo $m1;

$m2 = mysqli_query($con, $m1) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while($m3 = mysqli_fetch_array($m2)) {
print_r($m3['href']);

if(in_array($var1, $m3['href'])) {

}
else
{
    header("location:no_access.php");
}
}
```

But i am not able to figure out what is the problem with `in_array` as all the pages are redirecting to no_access.php page and that page contents also not displaying but it says **The page isn’t redirecting properly**.

**Edited**

```
$q1 =  basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$var1 = "/".$q1;

$m1 = "select pages.page_id, pages.code, pages.page, pages.href, access_level.page_id, access_level.user_id FROM pages INNER JOIN access_level ON pages.page_id=access_level.page_id WHERE access_level.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
//echo $m1;

$m2 = mysqli_query($con, $m1) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while($m3 = mysqli_fetch_array($m2)) {
    $href[] = ($m3['href']); 
//print_r($href);
//echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/".$var1;
if(in_array($var1, $href)) {
 header("location:".BASE_URL."".$var1);
}
else

{
    header("location:no_access.php");
}


}
```

Comment: what you are getting in `var1` and `$m3['href']` ?

Comment: What @OwaisAslam asks is pretty standard to include in the question, and obviously will show you the problem.  How can you question the comparison of two things and not know what they are?  But as a hint, neither one is an array.

Comment: in $var1 - i am getting `"/pagename1.php"` and i am storing the same way in my tables, 
in `m3['href']` list of all the pages - ` /pagename2.php/pagename3.php/pagename4.php`

Answer (score -1):

try like this...

```
$m1 = "select pages.page_id, pages.code, pages.page, pages.href, access_level.page_id, access_level.user_id FROM pages INNER JOIN access_level ON pages.page_id=access_level.page_id WHERE access_level.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
    //echo $m1;

    $q1 =  basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

$var1 = "/".$q1;

$m1 = "select pages.page_id, pages.code, pages.page, pages.href, access_level.page_id, access_level.user_id FROM pages INNER JOIN access_level ON pages.page_id=access_level.page_id WHERE access_level.user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
//echo $m1;

```
$m2 = mysqli_query($con, $m1) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while($m3 = mysqli_fetch_array($m2)) {
    $href[] = ($m3['href']); 
} //close while loop here
//print_r($href);
//echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."/".$var1;
if(in_array($var1, $href)) {
 header("location:".BASE_URL."".$var1);
}
else

{
    header("location:no_access.php");
}
```

Comment: Yes now it goes to `no_access.php`, but if the match is found, instead of the message, it should go to that page. Now everything is redirecting to no_access.php, but displays message `Match found`

Comment: if it gets match on which page you wants to redirect?

Comment: Plz downvoter,.. can you tell me reason of downvoting?

Comment: @ Hikmat Sijapati : I have edited my answer. Please correct if i am wrong. Its not redirecting to no_access.php if its not present in array

Comment: No. I have put this code in a file called access.php, if i put it in header.php, whichever page i go it says `'The page isn’t redirecting properly'`, If i put it in the particular  page where i want to check , it doesn't work.